# Верно ли расставлены запятые? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Верно ли расставлены запятые в предложении?

> Если вы уже испытываете стресс, то время, проведённое в ожидании
> очередного лайка, сообщения, бесконечная прокрутка ленты в Instagram
> или любой другой соцсети только увеличит уровень тревожности и в
> некоторых случаях даже депрессии.

Или же стоит поставить запятую после «соцсети»?

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу здесь такие варианты.

1. Короткий причастный оборот (запятой после "соцсети" нет).
   Если вы уже испытываете стресс, то **время**, *проведённое в ожидании очередного лайка, сообщения,* бесконечная **прокрутка** ленты в Instagram или любой другой соцсети только **увеличат** уровень тревожности и в некоторых случаях даже депрессии.

В придаточном предложении два подлежащих (*время, прокрутка*), поэтому требуется множественное число сказуемого (*увеличат*).

2. Длинный причастный оборот (запятая после "соцсети").
   Если вы уже испытываете стресс, то **время,** ***проведённое в ожидании** очередного лайка, сообщения, **в бесконечной прокрутке** ленты в Instagram или любой другой соцсети,* только увеличит уровень тревожности и в некоторых случаях даже депрессии.

В этом случае в придаточном предложении одно подлежащее, но необходимо произвести согласование: время, проведенное (в чём?) в ожидании, в бесконечной прокрутке.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, запятой там быть не должно. Причастный оборот начинается на слове "приведенное", а заканчивается на "сообщения". А запятые внутри данного прич. оборота расставлены между однородными членами предложения (в данном случае между дополнениями). Причин для постановки запятой после слова "соцсети" нет.

Comment: Чуть подробнее, если можно. Правила ресурса требуют развернутых ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Про запятую уже ответили, она не нужна, но вот сам текст представляется мне плохо читаемым (растянутым и перегруженным запятыми). Почему нельзя писать проще, например:

*Если вы уже испытываете стресс, то ожиданиие очередного лайка **или** сообщения, бесконечная прокрутка ленты в Instagram **или** любой другой соцсети только увеличат уровень тревожности, а в некоторых случаях даже могут привести к депрессии.*

Уровень депрессии — есть такой термин? Кажется, там другая классификация, например: https://vclinica.ru/stati/vidy-depressii-ee-simptomy/